# What does "collective regularity" mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In our class notes, our professor has the following: "Probability theory provides a mathematical framework and computational methodology for treating random phenomena when they exhibit some form of `collective regularity`, e.g. averages converge." What did he mean exactly by collective regularity?

Answer (score 0):

The professor was simply saying that to study random variables, you will have to make assumptions about them.

Sometimes, assumptions imposed on objects in mathematics (especially in the fields of analysis) are referred to as *regularity*.

For example, we might be interested in a sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ that exhibit the pointwise convergence $X_n(\omega)\rightarrow X$, where $\omega$ is a possible state of the world, also referred to as an *outcome* or *sample*.

> As an example of a sequence, consider the case in which $\omega$ is equal to of the six faces of a die and $X_n(\omega)=1/\omega$. In this case, $X_n(\omega)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

The average, or *expectation*, of $X_n$ is denoted $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$. We might be interested in computing the quantity $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n].$$ Can we claim $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\mathbb{E}[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n]=\mathbb{E}[X]?$$

As it turns out, we cannot always claim the above without *sufficient regularity*.

Theorems like the Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT) or Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT) tell us when it is okay to claim the above, and they each require some form of regularity on the sequence $X_1, X_2, \ldots$.

> I would not worry if this is confusing right now. You will get a feel for things as the semester progresses.